# Why does getContentPane().getWidth() return 0?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, contentpane

I have a class `Window` that extends `JFrame` and a class `Content` that extends `JPanel`. An object of `Content` is added to an object of `Window`.

Class `Window`:

```
public class Window extends JFrame
{   
    private Content content;

    public Window()
    {       
        setTitle("My Window");
        setSize(800, 600);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(getParent());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        

        content = new Content(this);

        add(content);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Window();
    }
}
```

Class `Content`:

```
public class Content extends JPanel
{
    public Content(Window w)
    {
        window = w;

        System.out.println(window.getContentPane().getWidth());
    }
}
```

Now I need to know the width of the content pane. But `window.getContentPane().getWidth()` returns 0.

Can you tell me why?

Comment: call getWidth() right after you call setVisible(true), it should return a width > 0

Comment: This is true, but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: if you need it before you set the frame to visible, then you need to call setPreferredSize() and the call pack() then call getWidth().

Comment: No, I need it in the Content class like in the code.

Comment: *"Can you tell me why?"*  Can *you* tell *us* why that value is needed before the `Content` is even added to the `Window`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using SetPreferredSize() then using Pack() is the key before trying to call getWidth().  This code is just your code with small modification, and it works fine.

```
public class Window extends JFrame
{   
    private Content content;

    public Window()
    {       
        setTitle("My Window");
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(getParent());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
        pack();

        content = new Content(this);

        add(content);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Window();
    }
}
public class Content extends JPanel
{
    Window window = null;
    public Content(Window w)
    {
        window = w;
        System.out.println(window.getContentPane().getWidth());
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine, but for some reason the window is not located in the center of the screen now?

Comment: Now I found out why: pack() should be used BEFORE setLocationRelativeTo(getParent()).